# Component Inheritance

Tags: nhibernate

Can anyone give/point me to 'official references' about component inheritance support in Nhibernate 3.10 ?
Already google it, but never find any reference about that.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but in what case would you have component inheritance? It sounds like you're using components for the wrong reason.

Comment: I have an User entity which has a reference to UserRole (abstract) as a component. Each concrete class has different additional property depends on role. Database uses "table per hierarchy" inheritance. Do I need to model UserRole as entity?

Comment: Look at the definition of component in OOP and you will understand why it's wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate (and Hibernate for that matter) does not support component inheritance out of the box. You have two relatively unpleasant options:

1. Map hierarchy as entities.
2. Write custom hydration/dehydration code using IUserType. This workaround is described in [this article](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/09/25/hibernate-component-value-object-inheritance-mapping/)
       (java, but should work for C#).

In the mean time you can [vote](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1152?focusedCommentId=44765#comment-44765) for this feature to be implemented in Hibernate and maybe some day ported to NHibernate. NHibernate [version](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3246) of this feature request.

Comment: Am wondering if a third option could be to use an interface with an Any mapping. Ayende has blogged about this, although not as a work around for value object inheritance. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here there's some doc but I'm not sure if this can help you:

https://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance

Updated

I think it's not possible! look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3739806/735864

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. It is an class/entity inheritance.

Comment: Similar case, but different problem.